# EM Express page of Oracle 19c is not opening

Tags: oracle, oracle-19c

I have setup the https port for EM express in the CDB database:

```
exec DBMS_XDB_CONFIG.SETHTTPSPORT(5500)
```

However while opening the EM express page `https://hostname:5500/em/` the browser is throwing "Secure Connection Failed" error. I am using Oracle 19c EE and firefox browser. all services including xdb> is up and running.

Can you someone help me resolving this issue?

Adding the lsnrctl status

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 31-MAR-2020 03:14:51

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                31-MAR-2020 00:07:11
Uptime                    0 days 3 hr. 7 min. 41 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/grid/product/19.0.0/grid_home/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/grid/diag/tnslsnr/ol7-orcl-19c-db-01/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ol7-orcl-19c-db-01.db.net)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=ol7-orcl-19c-db-01.db.net)(PORT=5502))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_home/admin/cdb1/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=ol7-orcl-19c-db-01.db.net)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/db_home/admin/cdb1/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "+ASM" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "+ASM_DATA" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "+ASM_FRA" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "+ASM", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "86b637b62fdf7a65e053f706e80a27ca.db.net" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "a2067c18400e18e5e055c4a9f9e8cd11.db.net" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cdb1.db.net" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "cdb1XDB.db.net" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ora19cr3.db.net" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "cdb1", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Post the output of `lsnrctl status`

Comment: @Sam I edited my post with lsnrctl status

Comment: Did you click  add security exception in the FF browser?

Comment: What's the version of FF and o/s.Is the instance on VM?

Comment: @Sam Yes It is in a VM (Oracle VB 6.0.14). OS is Oracle Linux 7.6. FF version is 74.0. I am not able to open the page from Chrome or Brave.

Comment: @Kumar This did not give any option to add the page to security exception.

Comment: If you have enabled host only adapters or bridged adapter use that ip address and try to connect FF from host e.g if I have host only adapter ip address `192.168.56.108` I can connect em express with url `https://192.168.56.108:5500/em`